# javascript array filter shows type error

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, array-filter

I want to get the value from array. It shows Type error. The code is

```
var user = "username6";
var result = categories.filter(x => x.user)[0].user;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

But it work in

```
var result = categories.filter(x => x.username6)[0].username6;
```

I want to give the "username6" variable in user. And execute

```
 var result = categories.filter(x => x.user)[0].user;
```

How it possible? Please help me?

Comment: Side note: When you find yourself doing `.filter(...)[0]`, use `.find(...)` instead (polyfill if needed; your transpiler should have one you can use): `var result = categories.find(x => x[user]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the brackets notation instead of the dot notation

```
var user = "username6";
var result = categories.filter(x => x[user])[0][user];
```

Comment: It's just a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable